# InfoPath cannot start Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Application

Tags: c#, .net, infopath-2007, msxml6, vsta

when i hit alt+shift+F12 in InfoPath (which should open VSTA), i get the following error:

[image]
Obviously no helpful information (thanks Microsoft.

I have installed MSXML and .NET 2.0 as according to: [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250982%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

> If your computer does have the Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 and Microsoft Core XML Services 6.0 installed before installing Microsoft Office InfoPath 2007, InfoPath uses the Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications (VSTA)

i double-checked the installations aswell: [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#net_a)

.NET 2.0 in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP
[image: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP]

and when i run [msxml6.msi](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3988) the wizard instantly shows:

[image: MSXML install Wizard]

i tried several reinstalls of all those features:

[image: change Office Installation]

(sorry for the screenshot beeing in german but i rly didn't get the installation wizard to change it's language, i tried everything.)

interestingly i can start vsta.exe standalone. But InfoPath cannot create a C# Project for VSTA.

now has anyone a good idea how i can get either better error information (i tried event viewer allready, didn't find anything useful) or solve the problem?

thanks in advance! phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that it depends on your Version of Visual Studio installed.
i **uninstalled MS Visual Studio Express for Web** and **installed VS Professional**. It's perfectly working now. At least Microsoft could specify this somewhere -.-

Comment: Hi its been so long but which verion of VS Professional did you installed?

Comment: @vickyshazad oof i'm afraid i can't recall and no longer work in this area.